# How to query load balancers with google cloud shell?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Is it possible to query the load balancers using the cloud shell? I need to find all the IPs hitting it.

Answer (score 1):

In GCP Load Balancers, the listeners are exposed using Forwarding Rules. Hence, you could use the following command for listing those via the gcloud CLI:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules list
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/list

Answer (score 0):

You can peek into requests hitting your configured HTTP Load Balancers in Cloud Console [Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-sdk#explore) by selecting `Cloud HTTP Load Balancer` resource type.

For detailed view you can [export request logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) into BigQuery dataset and perform powerful aggregations using SQL.

Note: information above applies to Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancer only. Network Load Balancer, on the other hand, just forwards packets to your VMs, so you will need to analyze traffic directly on your backends.